# Displaying a moveable character inside of a grid

Tags: python, console

I'm attempting to create an arena style game in the console but I need a little help. I've got the grid and I'm now able to move the player around but I don't think I'm doing it the best way that I could be. What would be a better way?

```
import subprocess as sp
plyr_x, plyr_y = (9,5)

def create_board():
    board = []
    for _ in range(10):
        board.append(['-']*10)
    board[plyr_x][plyr_y] ='o'
    return board

def print_board(board):
    tmp = sp.call('clear')
    for row in board:
        print ' '.join(row)

board = create_board()
print_board(board)
while True:
    direction = raw_input('Which way do you want to move? ')
    if direction == 'up':
        plyr_x += -1
        print_board(create_board())
    elif direction == 'down':
        plyr_x += 1
        print_board(create_board())
    elif direction == 'right':
        plyr_y += 1
        print_board(create_board())
    elif direction == 'left':
        plyr_y += -1
        print_board(create_board())
```

Comment: Note you can simplify your create_board() using board.append('-'*10) instead of the second for loop... and even as a one liner: return [['-']*10 for _ in range(10)]

Comment: If I do that, I can't assign the player location with `board[x][y]`

Comment: You should... make sure to use ['-']*10 and not '-'*10.

Comment: Works like a charm now (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

Keep players current location in a tuple (x,y)

Prompt with:

```
direction = input('which direction?')
```

clear old position with:

```
board[y][x] = ' '
```

update new location (x,y) (leave that logic to you)

update board with:

```
board[y][x] = 'X'
```

Comment: Alright, I'm having trouble looping through the 2D board to find the players location. Also, where should I keep the player's data?

Comment: Just define it, like (x,y)=(0,0). Then you don't need to loop to find the player's position, it is (x,y)...

Comment: I've got the player moving around now. I'll update this question to show you the code I have so far.

Comment: First you need to make sure your player is not going out of the board or you'll crash your program. Second you recreate a new board at every move which is a waste. Just create it once at the start then only update the old and new position at every move as suggested in my answer...

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to get around making a new board each time. Now I'll have to figure out how to keep from leaving the board, which shouldn't be too hard. I'm gonna try to put all of this into a few function to keep it better organized because I don't want a huge `if` statement.